# Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = p$ in a given metric space then the set of points $(p, p_1, p_2, ...) = S$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = p$ in a given metric space then the set of points $\{p, p_1, p_2, ...\} = S$ is closed.

I tried a proof by contradiction: supposing that $S$ is open, showing a contradiction, and then proving that $S$ is closed. However, I ran into the following problem.

We know that for some value $n \ge N$, $d(p_n, p) \lt \varepsilon$. We assume that S is open and thus, for any point $p_0 \in S$, there exists an open ball around $p_0$ consisting of the subset defined by {$p \in (p, p_1, ... ) : d(p_0, p) \lt r$}.

**Can't we set $r = \min ${$\varepsilon, d(p, p_1), d(p_1, p_2),...$} and thus prove that $S$ is open? Or am I missing something here? As for the proof, I really want to prove this using the method of contradiction specified above. Could someone lend me a hand?**

Comment: What does "set of points (p,....) = S  is convergent" mean?  Also, I don't understand why you are trying to prove S is open or S is closed, it doesn't follow that if S is not open then S is closed - S might be closed since it is a set of discrete points. Please clarify, we might be able to help.

Comment: @user247608 Nice catch - edits made

Comment: Just an aside: A set can be open, closed, both, or neither.  Most sets are neither open nor closed.  In other words, "not open" does not imply "closed."

Comment: @JesseMadnick But couldn't I go on (after proving it wasn't open) to prove it was closed by showing that for any point $p \in S$, there exists a closed ball with center $p$?

Comment: I know you specifically asked for a contradiction and I am interested in thinking of an argument, but as an alternative way, note first limits in metric spaces are unique and also limits of sequences are limit points (or some call them accumulation points) of the set $\{p_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. If you take $S=\{p_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{p\}$ then $S$ contains all of its limit points, since there is only one, namely $p$, and is hence closed.

Comment: I think you are going the wrong way here, I would try to show that the complement of S is open and thus S is closed.  If there's only finite number of p's in S, then its closed, so assume S has an infinite number of points. Since the sequence converges, any open ball around p contains an infinite number of points.   Since p!=q, we can put an open ball around q which doesn't contain p, so the ball will contain only a finite number of points of S, so we can shrink the ball down so it contains q but no points of S, so S' is open, hence S is closed. Polish that up.

Comment: Can I use my approach? Will it work? If it can how, and if it can't, why?

Comment: No, your proof is fundamentally flawed - you can't prove S is closed by showing its not open, that is not true generally.   Also your min(....) argument is not valid, the min() might be zero since you are dealing with a infinite set of points.  Go back to the criterion for convergence and consider a small open ball around p.

Comment: @ColeButler: It's fine to prove that $S$ is not open, it's just that that won't help you prove that $S$ is closed.  Separately, the two notions (1) "a set $T$ is closed," and (2)"every point of $T$ is contained in a closed ball which lies in $T$" are not equivalent: in fact, neither implies the other.

Comment: @JesseMadnick How come that is true for open balls and open sets and not for closed balls and closed sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1).It is possible that $S$ is both open and closed. For example $S$ may be the whole space.

(2).A set may be neither open nor closed so if a set is not open, it may also not be closed.

(3). To show that $S$ is closed: Suppose $q$ is a pont in the space and $q\not \in S.$ For brevity let $r=d(q,p).$ Take any $n>1$ such that $\{p_j:j\geq n\}\subset B_d(p,r/2).$  Take any $t$ with $$0<t<\min (\; \; r/2,\;  \min \{d(q,p_j):1\leq j<n\}\; \;).$$ Then $S\cap B_d(q,t)=\phi.$ So $q$ is not a limit point of $S.$ And also  $q\not \in S.$ So $q\not \in \bar S.$